# draw a elastic line in uiviewcontroller from touchbegin to touch move

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

i am implementing an application where i need to draw a line on UIViewController.

line should straight and behave elastically, like[this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUQam.png), 
you can take reference to my question from this [app.](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/jump-in-jack-ball/id406333786?mt=8)

i have gone through lot of tutorial, where i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)
and implement too, but out put is like : line is not straight and also not behaves elastically.

if anyone know how can i implement such line, please guide me.

thanks.