# How can I provide a divider-bar for iPad in the Interface Builder?

Tags: ipad, interface-builder, divider

I have a busy layout and I want all the information on the screen, but divided by the functional equivalent of `<hr>` in an HTML layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a 1px high `UIView` and set the background color to whatever you want.

Or the [harder way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone) using Core Graphics.

Comment: What if the UX reviewers want some border style?  Is using a UITextField and disabling the user interaction too much of a hack?

Comment: @mobibod: Not sure I understand. Are you suggesting using a UITextField for a separator? Also, if you have specific requirements, please include them in the question - you will get better answers this way.

Comment: Sorry for the frustration - I thought the reference to <HR> in HTML would suffice.  For example, it has many attributes for border style, etc.  Unfortunately, I have vague requirements to begin with and I did not escape the <HR>, so instead I got an <HR> in my question.  I will fix the description.

Comment: @mobimob: (I knew it was a horizontal rule.) You can apply border styles to a `UIView` by accessing its `layer` property. See the docs on `CALayer`.

Comment: Good point.  I like that answer.  I am using a UITextField and disabling the user interaction, making it really thin and no text.  I prefer the UIView under this circumstance.