# How starting point of line can be fixed in drawing using quartz?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, quartz-graphics

i want to draw a line in core graphics in iphone.I am using Quartz for drawing. I want to fix the starting point of the line. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a line just check this [How do I draw a line on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)

And to detect touches and convert them into points do the following.....

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Retrieve the touch point

    UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for [CGContextMoveToPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextMoveToPoint) in CoreGraphics.